# Transpose Array Into Separate Columns and Normalize Data

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, transpose

I have a string in Cell B6:

```
AB(1)CD(3)EFG(3)
```

I have a click and drag formula that will delimit each section of the string, starting in Cell C6:

```
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B6,"(",")"),")",REPT(" ",LEN($B6))),(COLUMNS($C6:C6)-1)*LEN($B6)+1,LEN($B6)))
```

I'd now like to transpose and normalize this data, getting it into the specified format in the included snip shown below (rows 13-15):

[image]

Comment: What version of Excel?

Comment: Good question.  How do I know? @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: Excel 2016.  But I'm not sure which version of Excel 2016. @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: office 365 @Ron Rosenfeld

Comment: Those are two different versions.  Which is it?

Comment: Excel 2016 @RonRosenfeld

Comment: Is using Power Query (Get&Transform) an option?

Comment: Unfortunately not, need a formula @RonRosenfeld

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work in Excel 2016

```
A13: =$B$6
C13: =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B$6,"(","</s><s>"),")","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[.!='']"),(ROWS($A$1:A1)-1)*2+1),"")
D13: =IFERROR(INDEX(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE($B$6,"(","</s><s>"),")","</s><s>") & "</s></t>","//s[.!='']"),ROWS($A$1:A1)*2),"")
```

Select A13:D13 and fill down as far as needed

[image]

Comment: This is great.  The only thing that may change is that there will be multiple rows similar to Cell B6.  Example ```B7: = FR(3)```, ```B8: = KI(Y)DEDG(8)```, etc.  Can the formula be flexible in taking in an array of input lines? @RonRosenfeld

Comment: @HelpMeCode You'll need to change the cell references and decide where you want the results.  Since you are working with formulas in Excel 2016, you'll probably have to do a lot of stuff manually.  This is where Power Query (or even VBA) would be much more useful.  Especially if you have more than a few rows with differing lengths.